# Regex for picking a Value After "-"

Tags: php, regex

Hi I need a Regex that can actually get any letter that is inserted after "-" dash e.g i have a string that says

```
 "UpTown-R" , "Category-C"
```

What I get in return is "R" , "C".

Comment: If there is always a letter after the dash, you do not need regex for this. You could use `explode`, and grab the first character from each element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If is always the last part of the string, you can do this

```
/[^-]+$/
```

see it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30apc)

`[^-]` is a character class that matches everything that is not a dash

`+` quantifier means one or more of the preceding element

`$` anchor for the end of the string

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
preg_match('/-([a-z])\b/i', $string, $match);
```

unicode compatibility:

```
preg_match('/-(\pL)\b/u', $string, $match);
```

The letter you want is in `$match[1]`.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are:

```
(?<=-)(.)
```

Results are in group 1.

Tested using:

- http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html
- http://regexhero.net/tester/

Answer (score 2):

A simple

```
-(.+)$
```

Will get everything that it's after the first dash; note that with this string `foo-bar-baz` you will match `-bar-baz`, and `bar-baz` will be in first group.

If you have to match only letters,

```
-([A-Za-z]+)$
```

Will suffice. Your result will be in the `$1` group.

Alternatively, why don't you `substr` your string, starting from the last dash index way to end of the string?

Comment: It will get everything from the **first** dash till the end, including the dash [Regexr](http://regexr.com?30apf)

Comment: By starting from the end I meant that also the dashes (if present) will be in the group. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this regex;

```
/^.*\-(.*)$/
```

this way you get everything after the dash

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use slow regex's for this, why not just explode the string on '-'?

```
$str = 'UpTown-R';
$arr = explode('-',$str);
$letter = $arr[1];
$letterSage = $arr[1][0]; // to be sure you only get 1 character.
```

This works just as well! Before writing regex's all over the place, think of these wise words: "If your solution consists of more than 3 regular expressions, you're part of the problem"