# Get the characters from a link in a table row

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

i am using Selenium IDE

I'm having a link in my href in a table like:

```
<table><tr><td>
<a href="#/FR/iWeb/Colis?c=9L07186140438-20150330" target="_blank">9L07186140438</a>
</td></tr></table>
```

I would like to get the latest characters of my a `href=` starting from `c=`, in our example it would be `9L07186140438-20150330`

I know that you can use storeText, but I have no idea how to do implement in my case to split the data, store the correct information to use them.
Does anyone, have a link or a solution that I can try ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this Scenario I'd use StoreAttribute to get the href, but that would take the full thing. If the section before the part you wish to store is consistent across all links then could use a regular expression to separate out what you need. (or even if the c= bit is consistent, as the regex I used only looks for the =, not the full href ahead of what you need)

so the Selenium test would look like this

```
<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>css=td>a@href</td>
    <td>href</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${href}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['href'].match(/[^=]+$/)</td>
    <td>url</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${url}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Which will give what you need. Log output below

```
[info] Playing test case Untitled
[info] Executing: |storeAttribute | css=td>a@href | href |
[info] Executing: |echo | ${href} | |
[info] echo: #/FR/iWeb/Colis?c=9L07186140438-20150330
[info] Executing: |storeEval | storedVars['href'].match(/[^=]+$/) | url |
[info] script is: storedVars['href'].match(/[^=]+$/)
[info] Executing: |echo | ${url} | |
[info] echo: 9L07186140438-20150330
[info] Test case passed
```

For more info on how the regex is broken down have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703039/regex-for-picking-a-value-after)