# Select a particular characters from an element in selenium ide

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

exact:Hardcover: `$79.99`

This was the total element. I need to get only the value `$79.99`.

> store  /  exact:Hardcover: $79.99  /i storeEval
>   /storedVars['i'].search($79.99)  /result

I have tried the above one but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing to do here would be to store the full element, and then break it down with a regex.

So to mirror your example here:

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>exact:Hardcover: $79.99</td>
    <td>full</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['full'].match(/[^: ]+$/)</td>
    <td>price</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${price}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Which gives the following output

```
[info] Playing test case Untitled
[info] Executing: |store | exact:Hardcover: $79.99 | full |
[info] Executing: |storeEval | storedVars['full'].match(/[^: ]+$/) | price |
[info] script is: storedVars['full'].match(/[^: ]+$/)
[info] Executing: |echo | ${price} | |
[info] echo: $79.99
[info] Test case passed
```

For info on how the regex is broken down refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703039/regex-for-picking-a-value-after)