# Extract only the value after colon in String in C#

Tags: c#, .net, split

I need to extract the if the string contains DataUniqueId . I should get the value after the colon (:)

For example:

```cs
string message = "You have the records with DataUniqueId : 2.1.23.55.66.577 . Your expiration will be happening soon";
```

So, I just need to extract the value of DataUniqueId after : means value = 2.1.23.55.66.577 
   Note- this value has . and it ends with a space then dot

Below is the code I am tring

```
  private static void ExtractDataID()
    {
        string message = "You have the records with DataUniqueId : 
      2.1.23.55.66.5778978 .Error - Your expiration will be happening soon";

        string expectedResult = "2.1.23.55.66.5778978";

        var dataId = message.Split("DataUniqueId");

      }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use the post preview to check that your post is formatted appropriately before posting - I've fixed it this time, but it's best if you do that yourself. Now, you've described what you want to do, but not what you've already done. I'd expect that a combination of `string.IndexOf` and `string.Substring` would do what you want. Have you already tried anything? What happened? Please provide more details about that in the question.

Comment: Did you consider using `Regex` for that?

Comment: @jon Skeet yes i did like that ..if message contains DataUniqueId but i am facing issues like if i do substring i get the value  : 2.1.23.55.66.577 . Your expiration will be happening soon"But I want only the value 2.1.23.55.66.577

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski No, i didn't do that i never used previously . it will be great if you can provide example

Comment: If you get two chars too many on the left, `": 2.1.23.55.66.577"` instead of `"2.1.23.55.66.577"`, then in your code `.Substring(someArg, someOtherArg)`, change the first arg (`startIndex`) to make it `2` larger. So `someArg + 2`. After that, if you get a wrong ending on the right, adjust the second arg, `someOtherArg`.

Comment: But it would be best if you posted your code; then it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for picking a Value After "-"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703039/regex-for-picking-a-value-after)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen i have added the code in which i am tring

Answer (score 0):

I hope this gives you an idea.

```
    string message = "You have the records with DataUniqueId : 2.1.23.55.66.577 . Your expiration will be happening soon";
    var indexOfColon=message.IndexOf(":");
    var indexOfDot=message.LastIndexOf(".");
    var id = Message.SubString(indexOfColon, indexOfDot-indexOfColon);
```

You might need to study the fixed pattern of the the string and use it to your advantage.

Comment: For me DataUniqueId is fixed . I will be getting for sure . I need the next value without colon and rest of string

Comment: Then the code snippet should help. Have you tried it out?